# How can I include Vulkan-hpp with glfw?

Tags: c++, glfw, vulkan

I'm developping a game engine using **vulkan** and **glfw**. As indicated [here](https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.3/build_guide.html#build_macros), with glfw there's a bunch of macros to include **OpenGL/OpenGL ES/Vulkan**. Since it is now included in the vulkan  sdk, how can I setup glfw to include **vulkan-hpp**. Do I just need to put **GLFW_INCLUDE_NONE** and add `#include <vulkan/vulkan.hpp>` or do I need to implement something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we take a look at `GLFW.h`, it just includes `vulkan.h` **only if** the `GLFW_INCLUDE_VULKAN` macro is defined. So if you want to include the `vulkan.hpp` file, just undefine the `GLFW_INCLUDE_VULKAN` macro and include the file explicitly.

Why? 
GLFW is a C library. `vulkan.hpp` file contains C++ stuff inside so there could be compatibility issues. That's why GLFW only includes `vulkan.h` and not `vulkan.hpp`.